# Configurar usuario en git

Tags: git

tengo que subir un archivo a github y por lo que entiendo los pasos a seguir son los siguientes :

1) ruta de mi archivo git init

2)  despues sigue git status

3) git add .

4) git commit -m "mensaje"

5) git push

pero cuando uso el comando git commit -m "mensaje"
me pone `"please tell me who you are "` y algo de git config.
Si alguien me puede decir por que no me deja crear el commit gracias :)
Aviso que estoy usando el comando de windows , también use el cmd de git y me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué te devuelve el siguiente comando: `git config --global -l`?

Comment: holaa , si ese mismo comando.

Comment: fatal :unable to read config file 'C:/Users/Usuario/.gitconfig' no such file or directory

Comment: Ejecuta lo siguiente: `git config --global user.email "tucorreo@email.com"`, luego intenta realizar el `commit` y comentas el resultado. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias ya funciona :) , una pregunta para que tengo que poner el email?

Comment: Puedes leer esto en la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup). Allí explica que luego de instalar `Git`, lo primero que debes hacer es identificarte, usando el comando que te di. En realidad, debes setear 2 valores: `user.name` y `user.email`. Sería bueno que le dieras una buena ojeada a dicha documentación. Saludos

Comment: Gracias , saludos :D

Comment: @MauricioContreras  te recomiendo responder esta pregunta si no existe en el sitio

Answer (score 1):

Al instalar `git` en tu equipo debes realizar el paso de identificación antes de poder utilizarlo.

Leyendo la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup), vemos que existe un capítulo entero para realizar la *primera configuración*. La misma debe hacerse sólo una única vez por cada equipo en el que se haya realizado la instalación de `git`.

Git almacena las variables de configuración en tres diferentes lugares, cada uno representa un nivel de alcance de dichas variables y además cada nivel superior puede ser sobreescrito por un nivel más cercano.

Para configurar globalmente la identidad del usuario  en `git` una vez que lo has instalado debes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Con esto ya hemos almacenado las variables `user.name` y `user.email` como variables globales de `git`. Las mismas serán usadas en cada proyecto que vayamos a realizar.

Puedes verificar que las mismas han sido almacenadas ejecutando la siguiente instrucción:

```
$ git config --list --global
```

La salida debería mostrar los datos que acabas de almacenar: (algo parecido a esto)

```
user.name=John Doe
user.email=johndoe@example.com
push.default=simple
```

Una vez realizada la identificación, podremos usar `git`. Éste es el único requisito después de instalarlo en el sistema. Sin hacer el paso de identificación no podremos hacer `commit` o `push`.

Como tip: si deseas cambiar la configuración de nombre de usuario y correo para un proyecto específico, entras en la carpeta del proyecto donde hay un repositorio inicializado con `git` y ejecutas lo siguiente:

```
$ git config user.name "Jane Doe"
$ git config user.email janedoe@example.com
```

Puedes apreciar que he omitido el flag `--global`. Ahora el usuario para ese proyecto en particular es "Jane Doe", y su correo también es diferente. Puedes verificarlo usando el siguiente comando:

```
$ git config --local --list
```

Espero que la respuesta te sea de ayuda.